# Transform Akka http entity byte string to Long

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

How to read long from an Akka-HTTP response stream of an unknown length?

example :

```
          val futureResponse = Http(system).singleRequest(
            HttpRequest(
              HttpMethods.POST,
              "url",
              entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, "somequery".getBytes())
            ).withHeaders(RawHeader("X-Access-Token", "access token"))
          )

          futureResponse.map {
            res =>
              res.entity.dataBytes
                .map(convertToLong) // convert to long/int
                .grouped(2) // group two elments together
                .map(getRelation)// do some transform
                .runWith(someSink) // write to sink

          }
```

how can we transform `ByteString` to the `Long` the above stream?

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that takes a ByteString and return an option of a Long ByteString => Option[Long]

```
def toLong(x: ByteString): Option[Long] = {
 try{
     Some(x.decodeString("UTF-8").toLong)
     } catch {
      case e: Exception => None 
    }
}
```

Comment: Or shorter: `def toLong(x: ByteString): Option[Long] = Try(x.decodeString("UTF-8").toLong).toOption`